# What is missing from these Oracle Solaris 11.4 firewall rules to allow traffic

Tags: solaris, firewall, oracle-database

I am trying to reach a separate, in-house application server from our Solaris server. The only firewalls that exist between these two are the native firewalls.

We have set the following rules on the Solaris firewall:

```
pass quick on pub_net inet proto {tcp, udp} to port XXXX flags any keep state (sloppy)

pass quick from SolarisIP to applicationIP keep state (sloppy)
```

The traffic is not making it out of the Solaris server. The application server does accept traffic on the specified port. If I understand the second rule it should be opening a point to point connection between the servers for any port.

Running curl from the command line of the Solaris server fails to connect. We have the same rules in place in another Solaris node and it is able to reach the same application server with no issue.

Comment: Then the firewall is perhaps not the problem?

Comment: I'd considered that but I'm not certain what else could be causing the issue. This Solaris server houses the database for our largest and most used application.

Comment: By which I assume it's perfectly capable of answering incoming traffic. In Linux terminology, a fw can allow established traffic but block new connections. Can you tell your fw to log what it's blocking?